# Trouble with getting currency code/symbol based on Windows settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I need to get currency code (like USD) and symbol (like $), based on computer settings, on which application will be deployed.
Sample code:

```
var currentRegionInfo = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion;
var currencySymbol = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
var currencyCode = currentRegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol;

console.log(currentRegionInfo);     //"DE"
console.log(currencySymbol);        //"zł" (polish currency)
console.log(currencyCode);          //"EUR"
```

I was trying to set different localization settings in Windows, different currency code in advanced settings etc., but after resetting everything, and setting to Germany, the currencySymbol as shown above is Polish currency, not the German one.

The question is: **Is this code correct, in terms of using this RegionInfo and CultureInfo? Where these settings come from, what should i set in Windows?**

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Do you want the currency of the server where the api is deployed. Or the currency of the user that calls the api ? Or something else ?

Comment: currency of the server where the api is deployed

Comment: There are two different settings: English Windows 11: "Country or region" and "Regional format" Both need to be set to Germany to get the results you desire